# Question on CREATE OR REPLACE and Updating Database Dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, mariadb

I'm currently using XAMPP , MariaDB Version 10.4.17 to store data transmitted via HTTP POST using PHP files but I have an issue with the **CREATE OR REPLACE Function**

```
$query0= " DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Gamma; ";
        $query1= "CREATE DATABASE Gamma";
        $query2=" USE Gamma";
        $query3="**CREATE TABLE OR REPLACE** Gamma.Tesla(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, logtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, IMFV float NOT NULL, IMMV float NOT NULL, SMFV float NOT NULL, SMMV float NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))";
        $query4= "**CREATE TABLE OR REPLACE** Gamma.Imagevalues(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Imageid int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))";
```

If I delete the Tesla Table, why does it not automatically re-create the table upon receiving new data from a HTTP POST

Also, how do I actually make sure the **ID Column** with Autoincrement enabled have their values reset if there is some data missing like the example below:

```
| id | Values | Log Time     |
| ---| -------| -------------|
| 1  | 20     | April 2 22:15|
| 2  | 100    | April 2 22:20| // DELETE ROW 2
| 3  | 35     | April 2 22:30|
| 4  | 65     | April 2 22:50|
```

When it recieves a data later at Apr 3 00:10

```
| id | Values | Log Time     |
| ---| -------| -------------|
| 1  | 20     | April 2 22:15|
| 2  | 35     | April 2 22:20| // Updated ROW 2 with previous values
| 3  | 65     | April 2 22:30|
| 4  | 99     | April 3 00:10| // New Data POSTED at Apr 3 00:10
```

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE OR REPLACE` is not applicable to [`CREATE TABLE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

You need 2 separate statements - firstly you must drop existing table (if it exists) then create a table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Gamma.Tesla;
CREATE TABLE Gamma.Tesla( .. );
```